# Codeigniter update table column with different values

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have the following records in my table:

```
id            status         

129           'Ready'           
129           'Ready'          
129           'Confirm'          
129           'Confirm'        
129           'Processing'        
130           'Confirm'
```

What I am trying to change is change the status according to id based on user input.

I am capturing user input in my controller as below:

```
$id= $this->input->post("id");
$confirm = $this->input->post("confirm");
$processing = $this->input->post("processing");
$ready = $this->input->post("ready");
$delivered = $this->input->post("delivered");
```

an example of user input values is as follows:

```
   $id= 129
   $confirm = 1
   $processing = 2
   $ready = 2
   $delivered = 0
```

This basically means that all rows with id 129 should have status in the order, confirm should appear once, processing twice, ready ready and no delivered.

How can I update the status so that it would be like below using the above input data:

```
id            status 
129           'Ready'
129           'Ready' 
129           'Confirm'
129           'Processing' 
129           'Processing' 
130           'Confirm'
```

In my model I tried as below but it's not working.

```
public function update_status($serialized,$confirm,$processing,$ready,$delivered) {
$data = array(
'status' => 'Confirm',  
);
            $this->db->where('is_serialized', $serialized);
            $this->db->limit($confirm);
            $this->db->update('items', $data);`$data = array(
'status' => 'Processing',   
);
            $this->db->where('is_serialized', $serialized);
            $this->db->limit($processing);
            $this->db->update('items', $data);
$data = array(
'status' => 'Ready',    
);
            $this->db->where('is_serialized', $serialized);
            $this->db->limit($ready);
            $this->db->update('items', $data);
$data = array(
'status' => 'Delivered',    
);
            $this->db->where('is_serialized', $serialized);
            $this->db->limit($delivered);
            return $this->db->update('items', $data); }
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

`

Comment: i'm sorry but this makes no sense. assuming the table only has 2 columns, and that id isn't unique, you can't select a specific column to change hence you are trying to do some wacky limits to achieve this. i'm assuming you are doing an ordering system where items can be dispatched at different paces, you should really revise your schema. this is unwieldy. the folks over at https://dba.stackexchange.com/ might be able to help

Comment: sorry if it is not very clear, the table has other columns but I didn't list them because the change I am seeking involves there two only. What I am trying to get is enable a user to change the status of a row or rows with a particular id. For eg, there are two rows of id 129 having status as ready, if the user want to change one or both these rows to status processing, how to do that?

Comment: for ALL `$this->db->where('status', 'Ready');  $this->db->update('table', array('status' => 'Processing');` however I wouldn't suggest using strings and instead use number codes 1, confirm; 2, ready; .etc. and define those codes according to their string values in a separate table. I still don't think this is the most efficient/right way to do this because if user wants to change one row, you don't have a unique column (?) so your left doing less than efficient methods.

Comment: the number actually stand for how many rows to change, eg. if confirm is 2 it need to change 2 rows having ready value to confirm value.

Comment: "if the user want to change one or both" hence you need to know which row with id `129` and status `ready` to change. doesn't this matter? or do you just want to arbitrarily choose a row with id `129` and status `ready` and change its value.

Comment: whatever row/rows with status ready would do fine. One thing I need to make sure is the rows to be changed should be according to this order: All rows will start with a confirm status, then go to processing, ready, delivered. So if a user wants to change status of say two items from confirm to processing, the affected rows should be having confirm status only, likewise if the user wants to change a status of 1 or more items from ready to delivered, the row/rows affected should have ready status

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179943/discussion-between-alex-and-hamza-zahir).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
function update_status($id, $serialized, $confirm = 0, $processing = 0, $ready = 0, $delivered = 0) {
    if (count($confirm) > 0) {
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->where('is_serialized', $serialized);
        $this->db->limit($confirm);
        $this->db->update('items', array('status' => 'Confirm'));
    }
    if (count($processing) > 0) {
        $this->db->where('status', 'Confirm');
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->where('is_serialized', $serialized);
        $this->db->limit($processing);
        $this->db->update('items', array('status' => 'Processing'));
    }
    if (count($ready) > 0) {
        $this->db->where('status', 'Processing');
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->where('is_serialized', $serialized);
        $this->db->limit($ready);
        $this->db->update('items', array('status' => 'Ready'));
    }
    if (count($delivered) > 0) {
        $this->db->where('status', 'Ready');
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->where('is_serialized', $serialized);
        $this->db->limit($delivered);
        $this->db->update('items', array('status' => 'Delivered'));
    }
}
```